# Main program window sometimes hides behind previous window when opening from installer

Tags: c#, winforms, installation, window, modal-dialog

I have tried two installers - Setup2go, and Installmate Builder, and I have the same problem. At the last window of the install, I select the option to "Open program after installation finish", and sometimes (about 10% of the time?), my (Winforms) app's main window will open behind the Windows Explorer directory window I used to open the installation exe from.

The frustrating thing is - I am having trouble reproducing the problem reliably (the problem seems to occur around 10-20% of the time). I am using Windows 7 if that makes any difference. To clarify, if I open up the executable directly (rather than from the installation exe), the problem never occurs.

My knowledge on this kind of thing is limited - I recall a similar frustration happening with the MessageBox from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467403/dialog-messagebox-sometimes-hidden-behind-the-main-form)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It does not happen when you launch the app directly from installer because the shell allows it to “steal” the focus. When you launch it from the installer, the last interaction happens in the installer app. The system prevents the new window from stealing the focus from your installer. If installer window closes, then the explorer window which you used to start the installer is activated. Since the switch of the foreground window happened recently, the system does not allow to change the foreground window.

On the other hand, if your application window is shown before the installer window disappears from the screen, the the app will be placed below the installer in the Z-order; and when the installer window is finally hidden, the application window is activated.

So it's all related to timing between showing and hiding windows.
<sub>Although I am not expert in this area. You can use message tracers and WinAPI calls tracers like Spyxx which can give you more details on what happens in the system and why the new window of your application is placed below the Explorer window.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the window's title isn't changed, until the last possible moment. I moved the `Text = "blahblah"` line out of the Form_load event, and into the Form1_Shown event, and now the hidden taskbar icon problem has vanished. Also, the window doesn't flicker when it's loading.